# Creating n linked lists in c

Tags: c, input, linked-list

I was wondering if it was possible to input an integer n and be able to make n linked list nodes. How would I be able to scan an integer, and then input 3 strings to put inside of that node so that I can call upon and compare it with other nodes later? And how would I continuously do that for however many nodes I wanna make?
I know if it is possible I can use a for loop do to keep adding nodes I just need to know what my syntax would be if I wanted to make however many linked lists I needed.

Comment: Hello Maria, your question currently is way too broad to be answered. This site aims for objective and direct Q&A. Please check the [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. I also recommend reading a little more on linked lists and recursion. There is plenty of material on that to study, and it would surely help you narrow down your question.

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion?

Comment: "I can use a for loop to to the recursion part" - Wait, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to ***n*** linked list ***nodes*** then yes, it is possible. Generally if you know in advance how many nodes you need you could simply use an array. Usually linked lists are useful when you do not know in advance the size of the list and know that it can fluctuate often (example: simulating a stack - push/pop operators).

That said, a linked list node can be defined as a struct with a data field and a pointer field that points to the next node.

```
struct node {
    int some_data;
    struct node *next_node;
};
```

Notice that the second field is called *next_node* and is of type *pointer to struct node*.

You can then define a function that takes a node as a parameter, allocates a new node (read about the **malloc** function and about the **free** function) and points it at the argument node. This would be one way of pushing data to the list.

Regarding your question about having 2 data values in the node - that is also possible because you are the one defining your node struct. Simply add another field to the struct.

```
struct node {
    int first_data_value;
    int second_data_value;
    struct node *next_node;
    float third_data_value;
};
```

Also note that pointer variables like **int *item** or **struct node *node** hold memory addresses. This is how the linked list works! The **next** field in the struct holds a memory address. When that memory address is the address of another node, they are said to be connected.

Comment: to follow up, would I then be able to put those data values into a stack or have I already created a stack? sorry if this seems very vague I'm just trying to sum up the ideas of my assignment without going into the full details

Comment: A stack is just a data structure that can be created as a linked list. It doesn't have to be a list - it could be an array or just a flat address space. You should read about some C fundamentals such as variables, pointer variables and pointers (memory addresses). Once you become more acquainted with the language, read about techniques like recursion and when it is helpful (it's a great technique for iterating over trees (another group of data structures that you can read about after the fundamentals)).